# Select field populated with multiple entries after one checkbox change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5

I have something in my mind, but I have no idea how to get it done, so I hope I can get some advise here.

I'm working on an activity registration app (using Laravel), where every activity will be registered. Very important is that we need to record who was invited and who actually attended. I already have this part running. My issue is more on the practical side.

I use jQuery Select2 for the multiple select fields for invitees and attendees. Imagine now that there's a group of users that need to be invited or attend virtually all activities, while the invitation or attendance of others depends on the type of activity. Using Select2, I can only select users one at a time and that sucks if you need to do that for, say, 50 users for virtually every activity.

What is the best way to have a "group" that can be selected, which selection fills in all the names of those in the group in the select field? Or is there a better way to get this done?

I'm seeing something in my head, where there are checkboxes next to the select field, representing the groups. When you tick a checkbox of a group, the select field is populated with all users who are part of that group.

I have no idea ow this can be done. I looked around and every search brings up select boxes populating select boxes. None handle checkboxes.

Any advise on how to get this done?

My PHP/MySql is intermediate, Javascript/Ajax is very basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One strategy would be to build a control (checkbox element) that will set or toggle the selection of your group of users whenever it's clicked.  Say we have the following markup:

```
<select class="my-big-group-select" multiple="multiple">
    <!-- assorted options here -->
</select>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-default-group" />
    Use my default big group of users
</label>
```

The Select2 API allows you programmatic control over the component it generates.
You can read more about it here:    https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic

Here's one way to leverage this knowledge using jQuery with Select2:

```
<script>
    var groupSelect = $('.my-big-group-select').select2();
    var groupToggle = $('.toggle-default-group');
    var myBigGroup = ["Aaron", "Beth", "Cindy"]; // assorted option values

    groupToggle.on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            groupSelect.val(myBigGroup).trigger('change');
        } else {
            var currentlySelected = groupSelect.val();
            if (currentlySelected) {
                var filteredSelections = currentlySelected.filter(function(key) {
                    return myBigGroup.indexOf(key) < 0;
                });
                groupSelect.val(filteredSelections).trigger('change');
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here's a CodePen that shows it all in action:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNQKOd

Of course you can build on this to make additional enhancements (the ability to select multiple groups, for example).

As an alternative, you may consider other code libraries like Bootstrap Multiselect:  https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

Hope this points you in the right direction!

Comment: It most certainly does point me in the right direction. I'll try it out and let you know how if it worked in my case.

Comment: This works great for me, @SimianAngel! I ended up putting the check for currentlySelected before the first if statement, because, if there are already names in the select, they should stay there, with the addition of the rest. Only issue I still have is that, when Beth and Dave were selected before I checked the box, only Dave remains when I uncheck the box. Trying to fix that now...